# I would like to create multiple tables in SQLite using Java String Array Loop. Bad programming?

Tags: java, android, oop, database-design, android-sqlite

I would like to create a SQLite database in my App, but instead of executing the strict text for db.execSQL I have this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = createCreateQuery(COL_APPLICATIONS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
}


public static String createCreateQuery(String[] COLUMNS) {
    String Query;
    Query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_APPLICATIONS + " (";
    Query += COLUMNS[0] + " " + COLUMNS[1] + " PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ";
    for(int i = 2; i < COLUMNS.length; i ++){
        Query += COLUMNS[i] + " ";
        i++;
        Query += COLUMNS[i];
        if(i < COLUMNS.length-1) {
        Query += ", ";
        }
        Query += ")";
    }

    return Query;

}
```

And obviously I pass in a Static String Array.

Is this bad programming? Does it use up an unnecessary amount of RAM/Processing as compared to

```
Query = "CREATE TABLE APPLICATIONSTB (ID INTEGER..."
```

For each Table?

Also, why do I get an error if I pass a Static String Array into my createCreateQuery if I don't put static in that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the SQL statement on-the-fly is fine. The time it takes to build the statement is nothing compared to the time it actually takes to run the statement.

There are some code issues, though:

- Don't append the `)` inside the loop.
- Variable and parameter names should be in camelCase.
- Don't build a `String` using `String += String`. Use a `StringBuilder`.

Modified code:

```
public static String buildCreateTable(String tableName, String ... columnsAndTypes) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("CREATE TABLE ").append(tableName).append(" ( ")
       .append(columnsAndTypes[0]).append(' ').append(columnsAndTypes[1]).append(" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT");
    for(int i = 2; i < columnsAndTypes.length; i+=2)
        sql.append(", ").append(columnsAndTypes[i]).append(' ').append(columnsAndTypes[i + 1]);
    sql.append(" )");
    return sql.toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(buildCreateTable("MyTable", "MyId"  , "INTEGER",
                                               "MyName", "TEXT",
                                               "MyData", "BLOB"));
```

*Output*

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable ( MyId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MyName TEXT, MyData BLOB )
```

Comment: I was reading that sqlite only uses Integer, Text and Real, is this correct?

Comment: @user3654055 There are five available data types in an SQLite:
1. Integer
2. TEXT
3. BLOB
4. REAL
5. NUMERIC